# Apache commons lang. Stringutils.splitByWholeseparator doing weird stuff.

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-stringutils

- As I understand from the official documentation, null as a separator string should split on WhiteSpace, so this `System.out.println(JSON.serialize(StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator("ab de fg", null)));` should produce `[ "ab" , "de" , "fg"]`
- However, what I don't understand is why is an empty string "", also splitting on whitespace. Following produces the same output.

  System.out.println(JSON.serialize(StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator("ab de fg", "")));
- Official documentation at https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#splitByWholeSeparator%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29 doesn't mention any such effect.

Comment: intentional http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java#2659

Comment: What would you expect from splitting by `""`? Internally, `""` and `null` are treated equal. `if (separator == null || EMPTY.equals(separator))`

Answer (score 1):

You're right. There's a lack in the documentation. `null` and `empty` String separator will produce a split on whitespace.

Internally the code is doing this:

```
    if (separator == null || EMPTY.equals(separator)) {
        // Split on whitespace.
        return splitWorker(str, null, max, preserveAllTokens);
    }
```

So these two calls will produce the same result:

```
StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator("ab de fg", null);

StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator("ab de fg", "");
```